# Stack Snippet dialog can format code. Does it work for more than JS?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting, stack-snippets

So I know that Stack Snippets can only run HTML/CSS/JS. But they have a neat formatting ability. You press the "tidy" button and it's like magic.

JS is part of the C style syntax family, so JS formatters usually work well with C style languages. (Obviously never use for Python.)

Is it a good idea to format C style languages with that formatter? Obviously, I would be watching to see if it's messing anything up. How much should I worry about maintaining the style of the code when using the formatter? I know that `{` placement is a religious topic.

I already tried it on some C code that I happened across in one of the queues. I had to fix the imports (which got messed up) before I saved it, but otherwise it was good (according to the user who criticized the format in the first place).

The next time you see some noobishly formatted code, try using the Stack Snippet Tidy button and tell me if it works. Does it ever mess up a certain part of the code?

Answer (score -1):

No, don't add more languages to the snippet format tool.

The snippets are supposed to be used with HTML/CSS/JS. If SO were to support formatting for other languages, we'd get even more snippets in those languages, with *"Run this snippet"* buttons that won't work.

A option would be to add a <kbd>Format</kbd> button to the answer field.

Comment: This is NOT a feature request. I am simply asking if other languages are lexically similar enough to be formatted by the tidy button.

Comment: Then what is the point of this question, if it can only be answered with _"Yes"_ and _"No"_? I'm sure there are languages that are similar enough. The snippets are _not_ the right tool for other languages, though.

Comment: You're missing the end of my post where I'm asking about code that tidy messes up. Anyway, if it is useful to use to format, it will be convenient to know about.

Comment: That would make this question too broad. Even then, what are you trying to achieve with this question? Do you want to compile a list of languages that sort-of work? Then what?

Comment: I just want to know if it's a viable alternative to doing it by hand. I'm also fine with a link to the parsing code.